# Add facebook messanger type round bubble icon while minimizing android app

Tags: java, android, popup

I want to add fb like bubble icon while i minimize app and it appears. And while clicking on it, minimize app gets open.
Note : not notification but only appear bubble that i can drag anywhere and click on it opens app again.
I would be thankful, if anyone can help me with this code